# How to add custom like button in shopify blog post

Tags: post, shopify, blogs

i want a custom like button in shopify blog post and show number of likes have on post.

please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Social sites like facebook , twitter  etc provide script , we can easily add that     script at blog detail page. 
 Ref. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button 
-j()t